# Python script not finding imported function

Tags: python, import

I have 2 extremely simple python files. I am doing this as a test to see if blah2.py sees the updated version of the two variables initially declared as None after the 2 second sleep. The files are as below:

**blah1.py**

```
from time import sleep
import blah2

movingVariable1 = None
movingVariable2 = None

sleep(2)
movingVariable1 = "sup"
movingVariable2 = "blahhh"
blah2.myFunc()
```

**blah2.py**

```
from blah1 import movingVariable1
from blah1 import movingVariable2

def myFunc():
    global movingVariable1
    global movingVariable2
    print(movingVariable1)
    print(movingVariable2)
```

I am getting the following error though, and I'm not sure why.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import blah2
  File "/home/pi/blah2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blah1 import movingVariable1
  File "/home/pi/blah1.py", line 10, in <module>
    blah2.myFunc()
AttributeError: module 'blah2' has no attribute 'myFunc'
```

myFunc() clearly is defined as a function though in blah2.py. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong in this basic example?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a circular dependency in blah2.py

In your example blah1 imports blah2 which in turn imports blah1 which will again import blah2 and so on...

Make `movingVariable` & `movingVariable2` parameters for myFunc and remove import of blah1.py in blah2.py.

Reply to follow-up

```
# blah1.py
from blah1 import movingVariable1
from blah1 import movingVariable2

def myFunc():
    global movingVariable1
    global movingVariable2
    print(movingVariable1)
    print(movingVariable2)
```

```
# blah2.py
from time import sleep

movingVariable1 = None
movingVariable2 = None

if __name__ =='__main__':
    import blah2
    sleep(2)
    movingVariable1 = "sup"
    movingVariable2 = "blahhh"
    blah2.myFunc()
```

If you change it like this it will work. Since when blah2 import blah1.py it does not see `import blah2` since then `__name__` will not be equal to `__main__`.

Comment: Does just importing those 2 variables, not the whole blah1.py, still cause the circular dependency? I knew it would if I imported the entire file, but thought it wouldn't with just individual variables.

Comment: Please accept the answer if your problem was solved.